# Attempting to create a UIScrollView inside of a UIScrollView, like photos app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having difficulty though. As soon as i make the content size of the outer scrollview be bigger than it's frame, the image that i'm zooming on it's subview (also a scrollview) is behaving weirdly.

Anybody have any ideas on how to do this? I'm making my own because i have problems with various ones on the internet and i also want it to support video, so i'm making it myself.

Comment: What exactly is this "weird behavior"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FOR ZOOMING inner scrollview you have to right this method.**

```
    - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        if(scrollView!=Innerscr){
             UIImageView *v=(UIImageView*)[scrollView viewWithTag:kTagImageViewInScrollView];
             return v;
        } else {
             return nil;
        }
   }
```

**and for scrolling images you have to write code in under method**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if(scrollView==Outerscr){


    }
}
```